# Cannot play mp4 input in AWS MediaLive

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-media-live, aws-mediastore

I'm using AWS Media Live for live streaming (together with AWS Media Store). My streaming flow works well but for some reason I cannot broadcast mp4 file as a filler. All seems to be ok, I cannot find also anything bad in MediaLive logs but all I can see in the player is black screen.

What I've checked:
MP4 source file is encoded with H.264
My input class is SINGLE_INPUT
My s3 URL for input is s3://assets/streaming/fill.mp4
Inside channel Input codec is AVC
The input is attached to channel

Could you help on resolving this? Streaming input works like a charm but I don't know why black screen happens when changing input to MP4 file.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description of the problem that you are facing, it looks like permissions issue with you s3/mediastore mp4 asset. Can you please make sure you have provided adequate access so the MediaLive can access the asset.

Please analyze the Alerts tab on the MediaLive channel for any 403 errors accessing the mp4 file.

Please review the following article for How to setup MP4 sources for MediaLive Channels:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/medialive/latest/ug/mp4-upstream.html

Thank you,
Hussain

Comment: Unfortunately, no alerts are shown and also role attached to MediaLive channel has S3 Full Access policy.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my fault, input attachment was set to CONTINUE as an end source behaviour, so when I checked screen the mp4 video was ended already. After switching to LOOP everything works great. Thank you Hussain!